# 6 millions of markers in folium/leaflet map

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

With the MarkerCluster algorithm, it's possible to cluster the nearby markers together, so the map is visually very acceptable.

however, I found that the performance and the response of leaflet map decrease with the number of markers inside it.

I still don't understand it but I found people talking about **Server-side clustering** solution instead of client-side clustering.

[This durable module project](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocluster) is a solution for big numbers of markers that uses this concept (*Server-side clustering*) in leaflet map.

My questions are:

how it is done in leaflet map?
how to make this solution in python at folium maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an Opensource solution for **leaflet** and **Mapbox**.

it is the [SuperCluster project](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster) created by the owner of leaflet.
it is **Server-Side Clustring** solution with node.js and **Client-Side Clustring** with MapBox.

the concept of these algorithme is explained [here](https://blog.mapbox.com/clustering-millions-of-points-on-a-map-with-supercluster-272046ec5c97)

Answer (score 1):

Server-side clustering can be accomplished with XHR requests.

The simplest approach would be to divide your map into squares, and have it switch between single-feature layers and substitute geoJSON/JSON layers using a `MAP.on('zoomend', function(e){});` event.

In an example, if jQuery is available, you can do `$.getJSON(SERVER_SIDE_URL, {VARIABLE: 'VALUE'}, function(data){});` on zoomend. Here the anonymous function will carry response data. You can use this data to either create a substitute LayerGroup, or a single Layer, while keeping track of and destroying its predicate.

The server's side will need to have access to the full dataset, and be able to either provide JSON for a single feature abstracting those nearby, or a set of features within the radius/square radius of a placeholder.

That's the abstract of one option. Alternatively, there may be market-ready solutions. But writing your own should produce a more efficient solution for such a simple task.